Error 1064 en CALL PR_Prueba(@Sale,'BDABM');
Este procedimiento se crea bien pero al llamarlo CALL PR_Prueba(@Sale,'BDABM'); Sale Error 1064 y no veo el error de sintaxis
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PR_Prueba(INOUT Salida BIGINT, IN Cond1 CHAR(10))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
    BEGIN
      DECLARE CSql varchar(100);
      SET CSql = CONCAT('SELECT Count(*) INTO Salida FROM ',Cond1,';');
      PREPARE Linea FROM @CSql;
      EXECUTE Linea;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE Linea;
    END 


¿Cuál es la versión de MySQL que estás usando?

Desde la documentación: preparable_stmt is either a string literal or a user variable that contains the text of the SQL statement., ver 13.5.1 PREPARE Statement. Básicamente preparable_stmt debe ser una cadena literal o una variable de usuario. Tenga cuidado con las inyecciones SQL. Intente: SET @CSql = CONCAT....

debes hacerlo asi:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PR_Prueba`(INOUT Salida BIGINT, IN Cond1 CHAR(10))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  DECLARE CSql VARCHAR(100);
  
  SET CSql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @Salida FROM ', Cond1, ';');
  
  PREPARE Linea FROM CSql;
  EXECUTE Linea;
  
  -- Asignamos salida a salida
  SELECT @Salida INTO Salida;
  
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE Linea;
END;

y lo llamamos:
SET @Sale = 0;  
CALL PR_Prueba(@Sale, 'BDABM');
SELECT @Sale;  


Sale el mismo error y heidiSql genera el procedimiento como lo escribí. Mi version de mysql 5.7
